# Save the input of loop without creating 3 different variables

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var rgb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
            var randomRGB = ("rgb"+"("+rgb+","+rgb+","+rgb+")");
            console.log (randomRGB);        
        }
```

I am getting this as input :

```
rgb(165,165,165)
rgb(195,195,195)
rgb(231,231,231)
```

what i would like to get is this instead :

```
rgb(165, 195, 231)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var rgb = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1));
    }
    var randomRGB = ("rgb"+"("+ rgb.join(",") +")");
    console.log (randomRGB);        
}
```

This way you're technically using one variable (an array of integer values) to set the RGB values, it's running a for loop to create the rgb array (or this can be done on initialization without using a for loop, but I feel this looks neater). This also means the variable is being re-initialized each time it runs the outer loop so you'll end up with different RGB's for the 3 times the outer loop is run.

Answer (score 0):

```
var color = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
    color.push(rand);
}
var randomRGB = ("rgb"+"("+ color.join(",") +")");
console.log (randomRGB);
```

Comment: `var randomRGB = ("rgb"+"("+ color +")");` This is enough. When converting an array to primitive, the `toString()` of array's prototype would use join for you..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Wow, all this time I really didn't know array's prototype was using join. That could have saved a lot of code for me. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
  var randomRGB = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
  console.log (randomRGB);
```

You need three variables if you want to store three values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
var randomRGB = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
console.log (randomRGB);
```

Or if you do want to avoid creating variable:

```
var randomRGB = "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1) + ")";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without a looping statement,

```
var getRgb = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
var randomRGB = ("rgb"+"("+ getRgb() +","+ getRgb() + ","+ getRgb() +")");
console.log (randomRGB);
```

If you want to do it by iteration then do like,

```
var getRgb = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1);
var randomRGB = "rgb(" + (["","",""].map(getRgb) + ")"
console.log (randomRGB);
```

Comment: But if i wanted to do it via a loop statement how do i go about it?

Comment: @Yunislav `map` uses looping statement inside of its implementation. If you want to use a for loop for sure then please prefer answers below.